# parse json object in django view

Tags: python, django

I have a form than i need to check if the emails on my form are valid or not here is my ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        function ValidateEmail(mail) {
            if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(mail)) {
                var postEmail = $("div.postEmail");
                
                if (!$("#members_email").val() == "" || !$("#members_email").val() == null) {
                    $.post(
                        "{%url 'validate_email' %}",
                        {
                            email: $("#members_email").val()
                        },
                        function (data, status) {
                            console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + " " + status);
                           
                          
                            postEmail.append(JSON.stringify(data));
                            
                            
                            // contaner.append("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                        }
                    );
                };
                console.log('email is true');
                return (true);

            }
            console.log('email is false');
            return (false)
        }
```

and this is my code in django view:

```
def validate_email(request):
    data = json.loads((request.POST.get('postEmail')))
    status=True

    return JsonResponse(status, safe=False)
```

it raises this error :
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'NoneType'
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'NoneType'

As the error says, the object that `json.loads` is trying to parse is somehow None, you would need figure out why the object is null, set a breakpoint in the validate function or print the value of `request.POST` to check what data is available on the server